# What is vtex LA font set and can you get it from internet

Tags: fonts

Any one have experience with VTEX. There seems a VTeX/Free(I guess its a free 
version of the commercial one VTEX)

On their website, it's said VTEX come with EC/TC font set 
http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/ecfonts/ecmain.htm

Also, it come with the LA font set(cyrillic font set)
http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/lafonts/lamain.htm

The VTEX/Free have the ec font set by searching the internet.

But I can't find the LA font set in the internet.

Any one have any thought?

Comment: Hi Yuping, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I removed the thanks from your question- it may seem strange, but the best way to thank people is to 'upvote' and accept appropriate answers :)

Answer (score 2):

The LA font set is "Computer Modern Cyrillic". This document will use them

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Москва.
\end{document}
```

The font should be in the distribution coming with VTeX. But they are also in standard distribution (the Type1 version is in the CM-Super package).